# Do math in package.json

Tags: javascript, json, package.json

I have some `.json` file and can I do math into it.

```
"delayedExchange": {
    "delay": 1209600000
},
```

Can I create like this:

```
"delayedExchange": {
    "delay": 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14
},
```

Comment: Not sure but most probably it cannot be done.After all it is a .json file.

Comment: no, json is a data format not aprogramming language, however, if you're using grunt or something else you can do the math in your grunt or gulp file.